# Spark Executor Lost issue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark job which runs fine for small data. But when data increases it gives executor lost error.My executor and driver memory are set at its highest point. I have also tried increasing `spark.overhead.memory` but still not able to fix the problem.
Is there any other solution to fix the problem?

Comment: can you post more details like how much executor memory, how many number of executors.... and stack trace of error

Comment: seems like --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=600 is the property not spark.overhead.memory

Comment: Hi RamPrasad,
Yes the property set is  --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=600. While writing I didn't write it fully.

Comment: I am generating the issue and need a fix for it.
Here are the details-
Total memory is 32 GB
Driver Memory - 256mb
Executor Memory - 512mb
num-executors - 1

I can get it solved by increasing the driver and executor memory in this case. But I need to find the solution if I am out of memory and cannot increase either driver or executor memory.
Try to look into the problem as if we had 1GB of memory only.

Comment: refer [how-to-ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Any Solution???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124380/discussion-between-user2606255-and-ramprasad-g).